# Groovy totalCount vs size

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Hi I'm trying to get the total Count of a list with groovy `totalCount` but it throws:

```
Exception evaluating property 'totalCount' for java.util.ArrayList, 
Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: totalCount
```

Is there anyway that I can get the total count with groovy `totalCount` instead of `.size`?

Comment: If this is related to Grails, then you should be expecting a [`PagedResultList`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html) instead of an `ArrayList` to get `totalCount` the way you are expecting. Make sure the list is.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour ? If you need the total number ot items in a list (or for any implementation of java.util.collection) use size()

Comment: I am after the size of the list. But I'm rendering many reateCtriteria lists after success of each if statements, eg: tot:results?.totalCount?:0 So I wanted this size of the list as totalCount.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include what you have tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do a criteria query in Grails the list you get back will only offer a `totalCount` if you invoked the query with pagination parameters (`offset` and `max`)

```
params.max = params.max ?: 10
def resultWithTotalCount = MyDomain.createCriteria().list(params) {
  // ...
}
```

A plain `list` call without pagination will return a non-paged list which does not have the `totalCount` property

```
def resultWithoutTotalCount = MyDomain.createCriteria().list {
  // ...
}
```